# Arrayformula with Filter of Mulitple Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I can't convert this formula into an arrayformula.

short version:
=filter(H2:AI2,H2:AI2<>"")

long version:
=if(H2<>"",H2,IF(I2<>"",I2,IF(J2<>"",J2,IF(K2<>"",K2,IF(L2<>"",L2,IF(M2<>"",M2,IF(N2<>"",N2,IF(O2<>"",O2,IF(P2<>"",P2,IF(Q2<>"",Q2,IF(R2<>"",R2,IF(S2<>"",S2,IF(T2<>"",T2,IF(U2<>"",U2,IF(V2<>"",V2,IF(W2<>"",W2,IF(X2<>"",X2,IF(Y2<>"",Y2,IF(Z2<>"",Z2,IF(AB2<>"",AB2,IF(AC2<>"",AC2,IF(AD2<>"",AD2,IF(AE2<>"",AE2,IF(AF2<>"",AF2,IF(AG2<>"",AG2,IF(AH2<>"",AH2,IF(AI2<>"",AI2,"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Neither returns an array effect. Dragging down the formula will work until a form is submitted. The cell in that row loses its formula.

[SAMPLE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsK3C.png)

[SAMPLE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSIMc.png)

Comment: First, you should never add formulas or anything else to the form intake sheet. That should be left untouched (and even hidden if you like) while a second sheet performs processing of that information. In addition, you haven't yet given enough information to solve the problem. What is in Column A of the form intake sheet? Your image shows that each person can choose only ONE one option from among 28 columns (H:AI); is this ALWAYS the case? (And if so, why isn't your form structured with ONE question that has 28 options from which to select?)

Comment: Do you have always ONE column full ?

Comment: Sorry that was just a sample. The form has multiple sections that will proceed to the next section depending on their answers. If the question is asking them to classify their answer base on a category (ex:category1), depending on their answer, the form will proceed to the next section asking them for a category2 which is currently divided into 28 sections (category1 has 28 selections). Was I able to explain it well thou?

Answer (score 1):

If each column has just one cell filled then problem is simple:

You take ALL the cells in the table and join together (I use # as separator) using textjoin.
Then I split them (which gives me a row of cells).

To have it as a column I use transpose at the end.

```
=TRANSPOSE(split(textjoin("#",1,A1:E10),"#"))
```

[image]

If there is more content in each row - it will be solved in a totally different way.

Comment: Note that this works if and only if you have one value per row; no more, no less.

Comment: Thanks for this! However, can I apply the formula into an array effect so that the formula will automatically be applied to a new answer from a google form?

Comment: I've tried to apply the formula in my sheet but i'm getting a #REF! result. I've attached another image sample above, hopefully that is clear as to my intentions.

Comment: How exactly your looked your column? What range did you use? As I look at sample 2 it should be B2: F - only area with responses.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Answer should only appear from column B to F and each row must only contain 1 answer. I used your formula in sample2 with this: 
    =TRANSPOSE(split(textjoin("#",1,B2:F),"#")), the result however is still #REF!